# Add column to table with values depending on dates

Tags: r, sum

I have a table that has dates as a number and a value with each date. Now I'd like to add another column, weekSum, which contains the sum of value over the last week. However some dates are missing (so I can't always use the current and last 6 rows). My table looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame('date' = c(20160309, 20160310, 20160311, 20160312, 20160313, 20160314, 20160315, 20160317, 20160318, 20160319, 20160321), 'value' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9, 10, 11))

date        value
20160309     1
20160310     2
20160311     3
20160312     4
20160313     5
20160314     6
20160315     7
20160316     8     
20160318     9     #17th skipped
20160319    10     
20160321    11     #20th skipped
```

I'd like to get the following as output:

```
date        value    weekSum
20160309     1       NA
20160310     2       NA
20160311     3       NA
20160312     4       NA
20160313     5       NA
20160314     6       NA
20160315     7       28    # 1+2+3+4+5+6+7
20160316     8       35    # 2+3+4+5+6+7+8
20160318     9       39    # 4+5+6+7+8+9
20160319    10       45    # 5+6+7+8+9+10
20160321    11       45    # 7+8+9+10+11
```

How can this be done?

Comment: why are the values for weekSum missing in the beginning? Shouldnt it be populated as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Convert the data frame to zoo and define a `weekSum` function which subsets its input to the last week and sums that. Then use `rollapplyr` with `coredata = FALSE` so that it passes a zoo object with times, not just the core data, to the `weekSum` function.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df, format = "%Y%m%d")
weekSum <- function(z) sum(z[time(z) > tail(time(z), 1) - 7])
transform(df, weekSum = rollapplyr(z, 7, weekSum, fill = NA, coredata = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
               date value weekSum
2016-03-09 20160309     1      NA
2016-03-10 20160310     2      NA
2016-03-11 20160311     3      NA
2016-03-12 20160312     4      NA
2016-03-13 20160313     5      NA
2016-03-14 20160314     6      NA
2016-03-15 20160315     7      28
2016-03-16 20160316     8      35
2016-03-18 20160318     9      39
2016-03-19 20160319    10      45
2016-03-21 20160321    11      45
```

**2)** An alternative is to fill in the value at the missing dates with zero and then just use `rollsumr` with width of 7.  `z` is from (1).

```
z0 <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day")), fill = 0)
transform(df, weekSum = rollsumr(z0, 7, fill = NA)[z0 != 0])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Could you maybe explain how the following part works? I asume it is to create some sort of vector/list of the past week, but I don't really understand how.  `tail(time(z), 1) - 7`

Comment: `rollapplyr` passes the last 7 points as a zoo object `z` and for any zoo object we can get its times using `time(z)`.  `tail(time(z), 1)` is the last (current) time passed.  `read.zoo` had created a zoo object of whose times are of class `"Date"` and for any `"Date"` class object we can get 7 days prior by subtracting 7.

Comment: Thanks again! I have one more question which I hope you could awnser for me. How comes weeksum knows it should take the sum of value and not of date since you don't specify anything about rows?

Comment: `z` is not a data frame.  It is a zoo object which in this case is a vector of values with a time index stored as an attribute.   The idea of time series objects such as `"ts"` and `"zoo"` classes is that one can deal with the values without regard to the time indexes and the time indexes are automatically handled (aligned, subsetted). Enter `z` at the R command line to see what it looks like.  Also try `str(z)` and `dput(z)`.  Suggest reviewing the 5 vignettes that come with zoo and its help files.

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this again, but how can this be changes so that instead of having NA as the first 6 values it shows the sum of the week so far?

Comment: Try `rollapplyr(z0, 7, sum, partial = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

With base R it can be done like this:

```
res <- merge(df, data.frame(date = seq(df$date[1], to = df$date[length(d)], by = "days")), all.y = TRUE)

res$weekSum <- NA
for(i in seq_along(res$sum)[-seq_len(6)]){
    res$weekSum[i] <- sum(res$value[(i - 6):i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
res <- res[!is.na(res$value), ]
res
#         date value sum weekSum
#1  2016-03-09     1  NA      NA
#2  2016-03-10     2  NA      NA
#3  2016-03-11     3  NA      NA
#4  2016-03-12     4  NA      NA
#5  2016-03-13     5  NA      NA
#6  2016-03-14     6  NA      NA
#7  2016-03-15     7  28      28
#9  2016-03-17     8  33      35
#10 2016-03-18     9  39      42
#11 2016-03-19    10  45      49
#13 2016-03-21    11  45      56
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `tidyverse` tools. This method uses `tidyr::complete` to construct the full date sequence, making it easy to take the current row and the previous 6 as suggested. Be careful here if there are 
`NA` values in `value` to begin with, as currently those rows will be filtered out at the end. Tweaks possible to avoid this case if necessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
df <- data.frame('date' = c(20160309, 20160310, 20160311, 20160312, 20160313, 20160314, 20160315, 20160317, 20160318, 20160319, 20160321), 'value' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9, 10, 11))
df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by = 1)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(
    newval = replace_na(value, 0),
    weekSum = newval + lag(newval) + lag(newval, 2) + lag(newval, 3) +
      lag(newval, 4) + lag(newval, 5) + lag(newval, 6)
  ) %>%
  select(-newval) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    date       value weekSum
#>    <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2016-03-09    1.     NA 
#>  2 2016-03-10    2.     NA 
#>  3 2016-03-11    3.     NA 
#>  4 2016-03-12    4.     NA 
#>  5 2016-03-13    5.     NA 
#>  6 2016-03-14    6.     NA 
#>  7 2016-03-15    7.     28.
#>  8 2016-03-17    8.     33.
#>  9 2016-03-18    9.     39.
#> 10 2016-03-19   10.     45.
#> 11 2016-03-21   11.     45.
```

Created on 2018-05-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).